# Silverlight performance design tips

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

What's your top 3 Silverlight performance design tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Only transfer the data you need -
  use lazy loading where possible (via RIA Services
  etc)
- Only load the bare minimum at start-up. Use a module-based downloading pattern (MEF, PRISM or other). Silverlight developers seem to have forgotten the 8 second attention span of Internet users still applies to them.
- Don't do excessive fullscreen animations and expect a high frame-rate on all machines :)

Answer (score 0):

- Use Virtualized UI (Virtualized stack pannels, ect..)
- Cache data client side in Isolated Storage
- Take advantage of MEF to reduce the amount downloaded when your app changes
- Use animated GIFs instead of Silverlight animation for loading animations